# Google drive does not sync over wifi

Tags: sync, google-drive, google-docs

My samsung note 5 has 2 google accounts.

1. When refreshing contents of google drive or google docs via wifi, neither of them can sync to fetch new information nor can it open existing files. When trying to refresh contents, this error message pops up: **'Can't retrieve file information. Check your network connection'**.
2. However, both the apps can sync with the google accounts over mobile data.
3. Already have tried existing suggestions such as, cache/data cleaning for the apps, restarting router, uninstalling/reinstalling google drive/docs, toggling syncs on for both my google accounts etc. Still the issue persists.
4. Have not switched to a different isp connection or a new router in a while. Currently using tp link WR741ND v4. It does not have any IPv6 toggling option.

Anyone facing similar issues?

Comment: Have you tested connecting to different WiFi Access Point/ISP? Also, do other Google services work properly on WiFi?

Comment: I did connect to 2 different ISPs other than my home network. One of them worked and the other didn't. Have been experiencing this syncing issue on some wifi only with google drive and google docs. Other google services seem to work just fine. I reckon this is a router issue because I tried everything else, as mentioned before.